# Find the inverse of $y = \frac{x^4-10x^2+13}{5-x^2}$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

Find the inverse function of $y = \dfrac{x^4-10x^2+13}{5-x^2}$

I tried to make $x$ the subject as usual but seemed to be stuck. Any idea how to continue?

Comment: Hint: If you let $u=x^2$, you get a quadratic equation in $u$.

Comment: This may not be the best way to solve this (Barry's suggestion is best), but series expansion of your function is quite nice:
$$
y=\dfrac{x^4-10x^2+13}{5-x^2} = \frac{13}{5} - \frac{37 x^2}{25} - \frac{12 x^4}{125} - \frac{12 x^6}{625} - \frac{12 x^8}{3125} - \cdots
$$
which seems to continue to have $12$ as a numerator and powers of $5$ for denominators.

Comment: @BenedictWilliamJohnIrwin Then are you going to use Lagrange inversion theorem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{x^4-10 x^2 +13}{5-x^2}=-x^2 +5 + \frac{12}{x^2-5}=y$

$x^2-5=t$

$y=-t + \frac{12}{t}$

$t^2-12+t\cdot y=0$

$t= \frac{-y ± \sqrt{y^2+48}}{2}$

$x^2=5+t =5+ \frac{-y ± \sqrt{y^2+48}}{2}$

$x= ±\sqrt{5+ \frac{-y ± \sqrt{y^2+48}}{2}}$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*  Interchange $x$ and $y$:  $$x=\frac {y^4-10y^2+13}{5-y^2}$$.

Now solve for $y$.
After substitution, use the quadratic formula.
Note that $x$ must be restricted to get a one-one function (the original function fails the horizontal line test).